# Как я могу проверить есть ли в строке python определенные символы

Tags: python

Мне необходимо проверить строку `'gkegfemeeуууее&@('` на то, что есть ли в ей только русские и латинские символы, без учета регистра, если в строке есть какие-то прочие символы - тогда ответ должен быть `True`, иначе `False`

Сделать это необходимо как можно короче, но чтобы при этом для меня было понятно, использование регулярок - запрещено.

Comment: А кто запретил Вам использовать регулярки?

Comment: Вот как буду понимать, тогда и будет разрешение :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Хоть и без регулярки, но попробую объяснить, что это достаточно просто и ничего страшного в регулярных выражениях нет.

```py
import re

regex = "^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]+$"
string = "gkegfemeeуууее&@("

pattern = re.compile(regex)

print(pattern.search(string) is not None) # False
```

Пример выведет False для строки `gkegfemeeуууее&@(`, т.к. она не соответствует нашему регулярному выражению. Разберём нашу регулярку:

- `^` -> Указывает на начало строки
- `[]` -> Тут указывает список из разрешённых символов (должно быть что-то из списка)
- `a-z` -> Все латинские символы в нижнем регистре
- `A-Z` -> Все латинские символы в верхнем регистре
- `а-я` -> Все символы кириллицы в нижнем регистре
- `А-Я` -> Все символы кириллицы в верхнем регистре
- `ёЁ` -> Особенные символы русского языка :)
- `+` -> Указывает на то, что строка продолжается и может иметь больше одного символа
- `$` -> Указываем на конец строки

[Пример на regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CR8QM8/1)

Comment: Спасибо что уделили время :)

Comment: А как можно добавить пробел, в качестве разрешенного символа в этом регулярном выражении?

Comment: `regex = "^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ ]+$"`

Comment: а можно ли указать к примеру символ `','` как разрешенный или какой-либо другой? Только чтобы были только те, которые я укажу

Comment: Да, конечно: `[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ,]`

Answer (score 3):

Вроде достаточно коротко и без регулярок.

```
check = lambda s: not all('a'<=x<='z' or 'а'<=x<='я' for x in s.lower())
print(check('gkegfemeeуууее&@('))
```

Answer (score 2):

Ещё как вариант проходиться циклом по строке и смотреть входит ли числовое представление символа в заданные диапазоны под латинские символы и кириллицу

```
# LATIN_RANGE = (65, 122)
# CIRILLIC_RANGE = (1040, 1103)
print(not all(65 <= ord(s) <= 122 or 1040 <= ord(s) <= 1103 for s in "gkegfemeeуууее&@("))
```

Answer (score 2):

думаю самый простой и короткий вариант будет такой:

```
print('gkegfemeeуууее&@('.isalpha())  # False
```

str.isalpha() возвращает True если все символы в строке алфавитные, и в строке есть как минимум один символ. В противном случае возвращает False.

Comment: Потрясающе! :)))

Comment: Не подходит, если в строке есть хоть одна цифра.

Answer (score 0):

```
return 'gkegfemeeуууее&@('.isalpha()
```

Для данной задачи идеально подойдёт встроенная функция isalpha(), которая определяет являются ли все символы в строке буквами, причем русские буквы тоже распознаются корректно.

Answer (score 0):

Как тут выше все сложно объяснено)) Все гораздо проще:

\d - это регулярка, проверяет строку на  наличие хотя бы 1 цифры

```
import re
text = 'привет 3'
if re.search('\d', text): # тут или True или False на выходе
   print('цифры есть')
else:
   print('цифр нет')
```

Comment: но в вопросе-то о цифрах вообще нет речи.